# Como receber notificações automáticas do PagSeguro?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou implementando na empresa onde trabalho, o pagamento com o Pagseguro. Até o momento, consigo gerar uma requisição de pagamento e também receber o código da transação em minha página. O problema está em receber o código da notificação via URL, já configurei a URL de retorno na API, mas ainda assim não recebo a mesma. Alguém poderia ajudar?

Para receber o código via QueryString, uso o código abaixo.

Desde já agradeço.

```html
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string notificationCode = string.Empty;
        string notificationType = string.Empty;

        //Pega dados vindos do post
        notificationCode = Request.Form["notificationCode"];
        notificationType = Request.Form["notificationType"];

    }
```